# Build failing, Parse-Server/Pod/Bolts

Tags: ios, heroku, cocoapods, parse-server, bolts-framework

I'm using Parse-Server/Heroku and just installed the `pod` for `Parse` in an iOS project of mine (written in objective C).
I am using Xcode Version 9.2 and pod version 1.3.1.
The macOS is High Sierra Version 10.13.2.

When I try to build the project, I get this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lBolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But `Bolts` seems to be installed, as a dependency when I run `pod install`.

Any idea about what I can do to solve the problem?
I presume the information I am giving here may not be enough. If more is needed to solve the issue please let me know what I should provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cocoapods, make sure you're opening the generated workspace and not the project itself.

Comment: Yes. I was opening workspace and not the project, thank you.
I solved the problem I had to put $(inherit) for the library search path and it solved the issue.